# pySNMP sequence on managed objects for setCmd

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp

According to the documentation the `setCmd` varBinds reference is a sequence of managed objects.  However, I have tried to pass a list `[(oid0, value0), (oid1, value1)]` or a tuple `((oid0, value0), (oid1, value1))` or a set `set([(oid0, value0), (oid1, value1)])` and all of them fail with the error "too many values to unpack".  I need to be able send a single set request with multiple varbinds.I can successfully send each managed object, e.g., (oid0, value0) as a separate `setCmd`.  Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: I found an extremely inconvenient way to do this.  I basically had to produce a string of managed objects and use eval() on it.  That is the set command looks like this:

Comment: # abc = [(oid0, value0), (oid1, value1), (oid2, value2)]
 mo_str = ''
 for each in abc:
     mo_str = str(each) + ','
    errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = cmdgen.CommandGenerator().setCmd(
        self.authData,
        cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget((host_addr, 161)),
        eval(mo_str[:-1]) )
  
This is extremely inconvenient programatically.

Comment: Use net-snmp and a shell call, `pysnmp` has a rather convoluted API for what should be simple things

Answer (score 1):

As shown [on the examples page](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/current/v3arch/oneliner/manager/setgen.html), passing a variable number of (oid, value) tuples to the setCmd() is a way to add multiple var-binds to request message.

The following code will build and send SNMP SET message with three var-binds:

```
cmdGen.setCmd(
    cmdgen.CommunityData('public'),
    cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget(('localhost', 161)),
    ('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0', rfc1902.ObjectName('1.3.6.1.4.1.20408.1.1')),
    ('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0', '1.3.6.1.4.1.20408.1.1'),
    ('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0', rfc1902.OctetString('new system name'))
)
```

Comment: I know what the example says, but as I stated, there is no way to provide give a variable in that form.  The example is great for fixed values as above, but try to do it with setting a variable as the multiple varbinds.  It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try asterisk

```
abc = ((oid0, value0), (oid1, value1), (oid2, value2))
errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = cmdgen.CommandGenerator().setCmd(
    self.authData, cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget((host_addr, 161)), *abc)
```